# post_class not including classes with hyphens

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the post_class function to add custom classes to my content in the content-page.php template.

I'm trying to add a class with a hyphen like this

```
post_class('class-name');
```

but it returns nothing on the div, whereas if I include a class without a hyphen it correctly adds it.

I've tried as using an array, and storing it in a variable but neither worked.

Has anyone ran into this issue?

Comment: Since the example under https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Adding_More_Classes uses `post_class( 'class-name' )` as well, I don’t see why this should not work.

Comment: Yep it's got me stumped, i'm not doing anything different to the docs

Comment: Try with php variable like a parameter --                                                              `$post_class = 'class-name'; post_class($post_class);`

Comment: @htmlbrewery Tried that, no luck unfortunately! Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of those typical WordPress bugs which have to do with hyphens, maximum characters etc. etc. Your may report this as a bug to the WordPress project.

The following will hopefully work (untested):

```
<?php
    $classes = array(
        'class-name'
    );
?>

<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

Sometimes WordPress has strange behaviours. Have you tried

```
post_class('long-class-name');
```

and

```
post_class('alotofchars-classname');
```

It may work.

Also make sure that you tried with deactivating your Plugins - it may also be a Plugin problem.

And ofc you have to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Adding post classes with hyphens works just fine (tested locally on the latest WordPress release).

The likely issue here is a plugin, or custom code modifying the post classes. The generated post classes, together with any you pass in to `post_class()` are passed through a WordPress filter. This gives other plugins / code outside of WordPress core the opportunity to modify the list of classes before they are used.

If you take a look at the code in your theme, or plugins you'll find something that is attaching to this filter and causing the issue you're seeing.

Take a look for anything that is calling `add_filter()` with 'post_class' as the first argument.